# How does cancelling an AsyncTaskLoader work?

Tags: android, loader, asynctaskloader

I've noticed the following functions for AsyncTaskLoader,Loader and LoaderManager :

- [**cancelLoadInBackground**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#cancelLoadInBackground())
- [**cancelLoad**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html#cancelLoad())
- [**destroyLoader**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html#destroyLoader(int)), [**abandon**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html#abandon()), [**reset**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html#reset())

Thing is, I don't get how they work:

1. What's the difference between them?
2. Does any of them call "interrupt" on the thread of the loader?  If not, is it possible ?
3. How can the loader halt its operation when those functions get called?
4. How can the loader cancel itself (since both functions need to run on the UI thread only) ?
5. Does destroy/reset/abandon a loader also cancels it?
6. Will "[**isLoadInBackgroundCanceled**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#isLoadInBackgroundCanceled())" return true even if the loader hasn't started yet?
7. How can the UI thread know that a loader was cancelled? Should it use "[**isLoadInBackgroundCanceled**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#isLoadInBackgroundCanceled())" ?
8. What's the typical thing to do to cancel a loader? to restart a loader? To restart a loader but with different input?